# KnockoutJS binding fail when creating a ChoiceFieldGroup using office-ui-fabric-js

Tags: knockout.js, office-js, office-ui-fabric

I'm creating an add-ins for Outlook (using office-ui-fabric-js and knockoutjs) which uses a *ChoiceFieldGroup* component.

When I create the *ChoiceFieldGroup* like the example at https://dev.office.com/fabric-js/Components/ChoiceFieldGroup/ChoiceFieldGroup.html
then the *KnockoutJS* binding don't work.

Here's the code

```
<div class="ms-ChoiceFieldGroup" id="choicefieldgroup" role="radiogroup">
    <div class="ms-ChoiceFieldGroup-title">
        <label class="ms-Label">Include email attachments:</label>
    </div>
    <ul class="ms-ChoiceFieldGroup-list">
        <li class="ms-RadioButton">
            <input id="option1" name="emailAttachment" type="radio" class="ms-RadioButton-input" value="withEmail" data-bind="checked: includeEmailAttachmentSelectedOption">
            <label for="option1" role="radio" class="ms-RadioButton-field"  name="choicefieldgroup">
                <span class="ms-Label">With the email</span>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li class="ms-RadioButton">
            <input id="option2" name="emailAttachment" type="radio" class="ms-RadioButton-input" value="individualReferenceFiles" data-bind="checked: includeEmailAttachmentSelectedOption">
            <label for="option2" role="radio" class="ms-RadioButton-field"  name="choicefieldgroup">
                <span class="ms-Label">As individual reference files</span>
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(() => {    
     const ChoiceFieldGroupElements = document.querySelectorAll(".ms-ChoiceFieldGroup");
     for (let i = 0; i < ChoiceFieldGroupElements.length; i++) {
       new fabric['ChoiceFieldGroup'](ChoiceFieldGroupElements[i]);
     }
  }
</script>
```

However if I create the *ChoiceFieldGroup* without the *fabricjs*, using standard HTML only then it works.

Here's the code

```
<div>
    <input type="radio" id="contactChoice1"
             name="contact" value="email" data-bind="checked: includeEmailAttachmentSelectedOption">
    <label for="contactChoice1">Email</label>

    <input type="radio" id="contactChoice2"
             name="contact" value="phone" data-bind="checked: includeEmailAttachmentSelectedOption">
    <label for="contactChoice2">Phone</label>

    <input type="radio" id="contactChoice3"
             name="contact" value="mail" data-bind="checked: includeEmailAttachmentSelectedOption">
    <label for="contactChoice3">Mail</label>
</div>
```

Can anyone please tell me why using the *fabricjs* way do not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because Fabric is looking at the `aria-checked` property rather than `checked`.

If you look at the [underlying code](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-js/blob/master/src/components/RadioButton/RadioButton.ts), you'll find this snippet:

```
if (this._choiceField.getAttribute("aria-checked") === "true") {
  this._choiceField.classList.add("is-checked");
}
```

Try switching your `data-bind` attribute to 
`"aria-checked: includeEmailAttachmentSelectedOption"`:

```
<div class="ms-ChoiceFieldGroup" id="choicefieldgroup" role="radiogroup">
    <div class="ms-ChoiceFieldGroup-title">
        <label class="ms-Label">Include email attachments:</label>
    </div>
    <ul class="ms-ChoiceFieldGroup-list">
        <li class="ms-RadioButton">
            <input id="option1" name="emailAttachment" type="radio" class="ms-RadioButton-input" 
                   value="withEmail" data-bind="aria-checked: includeEmailAttachmentSelectedOption">
            <label for="option1" role="radio" class="ms-RadioButton-field" name="choicefieldgroup">
                <span class="ms-Label">With the email</span>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li class="ms-RadioButton">
            <input id="option2" name="emailAttachment" type="radio" class="ms-RadioButton-input" 
                   value="individualReferenceFiles" data-bind="aria-checked: includeEmailAttachmentSelectedOption">
            <label for="option2" role="radio" class="ms-RadioButton-field" name="choicefieldgroup">
                <span class="ms-Label">As individual reference files</span>
            </label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(() => {
                const ChoiceFieldGroupElements = document.querySelectorAll(".ms-ChoiceFieldGroup");
                for (let i = 0; i < ChoiceFieldGroupElements.length; i++) {
                    new fabric['ChoiceFieldGroup'](ChoiceFieldGroupElements[i]);
                }
            }
</script>
```